# Is it possible to return relationships between two objects in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am a beginner in SPARQL and I would like to know if it is possible to return relationships between two objects. For example I would like to write a SPARQL query which returns the relationship between Thierry Henry and Arsenal in dbpedia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ?relationship
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thierry_Henry> 
  ?relationship 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Arsenal_F.C.>
}
```

i.e.:

> show me the predicates (`?relationship`) where the subject is the DBPedia resource `Thierry_Henry` and the object is the DBPedia resource `Arsenal_F.C.`

..which results to:

```
dbpedia:ontology/team
dbpedia2:clubs
```

..which apparently means that Thierry Henry was part of the Arsenal team and belonged to the Arsenal Football Club. See the result on [DBPedia SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Frelationship%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FThierry_Henry%3E+%3Frelationship+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArsenal_F.C.%3E%0D%0A%7D).